# How to start emacs as service?

Tags: systemd, services, autostart, emacs

I'm trying to start the emacs daemon as a service but the service stops immediately upon startup.

in the [Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon) page is this service script for **systemd**.

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

but I can not get the daemon to start

**what am I doing wrong?**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Emacs: 25.2

Comment: What does `ps aux | grep emacs` output after you have started the service? Emacs forks into background when starting the daemon. The process is running, but it **appears** to have exited.

Comment: What does `journalctl --user -u emacs` show? Add that output to your question by editing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `systemd` service file seems to need some modifications to work. From the link you provided, the `--fg-daemon` option  is only available for *Emacs 26.1+*, whereas version below should use `--daemon` (was introduced in *Emacs 23.1*).
Further the `Type=` should be adopted to forking, since `emacs` is forking.

So the resulting `systemd` unit should look like as follows.

```
user@host:~$ cat .config/systemd/user/emacs.service 
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After you have applied your changes, do not forget to reload the configuration.

```
user@host:~$ systemctl daemon-reload --user
```

Then start the service as regular user.

```
user@host:~$ systemctl start --user emacs
```